# BigDecimal remainder method may return negative value, why?

Tags: java

Under what circumstances BigDecimal's remainder method would return negative value?

It is noted in the Javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#remainder(java.math.BigDecimal)):

> The remainder is given by `this.subtract(this.divideToIntegralValue(divisor).multiply(divisor))`. Note that this is not the modulo operation (the result can be negative).

Comment: Try with `BigDecimal.valueOf(-1).remainder(BigDecimal.valueOf(3))`.

Comment: From the docs: The remainder is given by `this.subtract(this.divideToIntegralValue(divisor).multiply(divisor))`.  `this.subtract` can return a negative value.

Comment: It basically follows the concept of the remainder operator `%` for primitive types: `int thisWillBeNegative = (-21 % 5);`

Answer (score 0):

According to the JavaDoc the result of that operation is calculated as following:

> The remainder is given by

`this.subtract(this.divideToIntegralValue(divisor).multiply(divisor))`.

So: if the instance of the BigInteger is pointing to a negative number, the result can be a negative number..

## Example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger("-100");
    BigInteger b = new BigInteger("3");
    BigInteger result = a.remainder(b);
    System.out.println(result);
    }
```

this will print **-1**